# Android Handle IntentService onStop event

Tags: android, android-intentservice

I want to handle [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) onStop event. IntentService will receive the Intents, launch a worker thread, and stop the service as appropriate but I have not found onStop method. It has `onDestroy()` but actually `onDestroy()` method can not be called.

> onDestroy is called only when system is low on resources(memory, cpu time and so on) and makes a decision to kill your activity/application or when somebody calls finish() on your activity.

Can I add my code in onStop IntentService time ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stopSelf()` to stop service. To perform task before service stops you can write your custom callback/ broadcast after your thread
 to notify UI.

Comment: Yes its look like writing my broadcast after service execution is only possible. But this is Download IntenetService with many download threads I need to handle event and send callback/broadcast after all downloads completed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are subclassing IntentService you should be using `onHandleIntent(Intent intent)` for the lifecycle of your service. Your service might be moving to `onDestroy` quickly becuase you do not have code inside of `onHandleIntent`.

Also it might aways move to `onDestroy` quickly because `IntentService` is auto threaded for you and might just launch the worker thread which calls `onHandleIntent` and move to `onDestroy`

Comment: The question is how can handle onStop IntentService ? service might be moving to onDestroy ? I`m not sure..